# Matrix restoring (modulo n)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $m,n\geqslant 2$, and $A\in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb Z)$ such that $\det A \equiv 1 \pmod m$.

Does it (necessarily) exist $M\in \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb Z)$ such that $A\equiv M \pmod m$?

Comment: As you can see from my answer, one can ask $M\in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb Z)$ with $\det M=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the [Smith Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) of $A$ one can assume that $A$ is diagonal with $d_1,\dots,d_n$ on the the main diagonal and $d_1\cdots d_n=1+mk$.
Then take

$$    
M=\begin{pmatrix}
d_1+mx & m & 0 & 0 &\dots & 0 & 0\\
0 & d_2 & m & 0 &\dots & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & d_{n-1} & m\\
(-1)^{n+1}my & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & d_n
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Clearly $$\det M=(d_1+mx)d_2\cdots d_n+m^ny=1+m(k+xd_2\cdots d_n+m^{n-1}y),$$ and since $\gcd(d_2\cdots d_n,m)=1$ one can find $x,y\in\mathbb Z$ such that $k+xd_2\cdots d_n+m^{n-1}y=0$.